# how to Read large input - 8MBdata in C

Tags: c, arrays, input

I have a problem where i have to read a large data (8mb) from the input file.I tried giving the size of array . Is there any effective way i can rewrite the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
 {

FILE *f;
char msg[9000000]=" ";  
int i=0;
f=fopen("file.txt","r");
while((msg[i]=fgetc(f))!=EOF){
        i++;
        }
 printf("\nThe data from the file is :%s\n",msg);
fclose(f);
return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Just don't store it on the stack, use heap allocated memory instead. See `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: Also note, while less portable (different API for POSIX vs. Windows targets), memory mapping is often helpful when you're trying to slurp binary data from a file. Do a search for `mmap` (if you're on POSIX systems like UNIX, Linux, BSD, OSX) or `CreateFileMapping` on Windows; particularly in the age of 64 bit machines, there is very little reason to prefer explicit file read/write APIs when you can just `mmap` the file and access it like a lazily populated array.

Comment: `static char msg[9000000];` is a simple solution

Comment: `msg[i]=fgetc(f))!=EOF` is incorrect (it will either never trigger, or give false positives on certain characters). You need to store the result of `fgetc` in an `int` and compare against `EOF`.  Also this loop should check it does not overflow the bounds of `msg`.  Using `fread` instead of the loop will fix all those problems at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you can just write what you read without saving all of that on memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{

    FILE *f;
    int msg;
    int inputExists = 0;
    f=fopen("file.txt","r");
    if(f == NULL){
        perror("fopen");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("\nThe data from the file is :");
    while((msg=fgetc(f))!=EOF){
        putchar(msg);
        inputExists = 1;
    }
    if(!inputExists) putchar(' ');
    printf("\n");
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. i tried to run the code and its looping forever

Comment: Thanks for your reply . Is it possible that msg can be an array

Comment: @tummalsr Couldn't reproduce "looping forever" in local environment. Yes, `msg` can be an array with proper code modification. What do you want to do with the array?

Comment: scanf("%[^\n]%*c", msg[i]);
 for (i = 0; msg[i] != '\0'; i++)
  m[i] = msg[i]

Comment: I am trying to save the msg in an array and then trying to divide the length into size of blocks. 
 len = strlen(msg);
 int blocksize = 4;
 numBlocks = len / blocksize;

Comment: for (x = 0, y = 0; x < numBlocks; x++, y += blocksize)

 {
 
  i = y;
  int p = i + blocksize;
  while (i != p)
  {
   
   pt = m[i];
   pt = pt - 96;
   k = 1;


   for (j = 0; j < key; j++)
   {
    k = k*pt;
    k = k%n;
   }
   temp[i] = k;
   ct = k + 96;
   en[i] = ct;
   
   i++;
   
    
  }
  en[i] = -1;
  printf("\nTHE ENCRYPTED message \n");
  for (i = 0; en[i] != -1; i++)
   printf("%c", en[i]);
  
  
 }

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", msg[i]);` is bad because `msg[i]` is not a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Non-static local variables are (typically, though not required by the C standard) stored on a stack. In most systems the size of that stack is fairly limited, often around 1 MB or even less.

Thus you should store the data else where, either on the heap or in static memory. Using the heap is the preferred way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX (8 * 1024 * 1024)
int main () {
  char * data = malloc(MAX);
  // add error checks
  int in;
  size_t position = 0;
  while ((in = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && position < MAX) {
    data[position++] = in & 0xFF;
  }
  // Note: data is NOT a string, no null termination
  // also check for errors
  free(data);
  return 0;
}
```

Two things to note: I'm also checking that the buffer won't overflow. This is very important, you should make that sure for *every* buffer you read from and write to.

Second, as any reference will tell you, the return value of `fgetc` is `int`. This is important because `EOF` can be a value that isn't representable with a `char`.

Comment: "Local variables are stored on the stack." No, they need not be stored on the stack. In typical implementation, non-static local variables are stored on the stack while static ones are not.

Comment: Indeed, I mostly forgot about static ones. It's late here :D @MikeCAT